# aws configure command giving [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am configuring awscli

I run following command:

```
[bharthan@pchirmpc007 ~]$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: adfasdfadfasdfasdfasdf
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: adfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasd
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: json
```

It is giving me following error:

```
[Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Any suggestions what may be the reason.

Comment: Where are configuring the CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You may have some bad sectors on the target HDD.

To check `sda1` volume for bad sectors in Linux run `fsck -c /dev/sda1`. For drive `C:` in Windows it should be `chkdsk c: /f /r`.

IMHO `chkdsk` way will be more suitable as it will remap bad blocks on the HDD while Linux `fsck` simply marks such blocks as unusable in the current file system.

#### Quote from `man fsck.ext2`

> `-c`     This  option  causes  `e2fsck`  to  use `badblocks(8)` program to do a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.  If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or directory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad  block  scan  will  be done using a non-destructive read-write test